# Laravel route not calling function of controller after adding auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-middleware

After adding the auth:api middleware, my route suddenly stops calling the function it is supposed to. When I remove the middleware, it starts working again.

api.php route

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/addloancontroller', [\App\Http\Controllers\AddLoan::class, 'store'])
    ->name('addLoan');
```

AddLoan.php Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\EarningsRecord;
use App\Models\Lender;
use App\Models\LoanLenders;
use App\Models\Loans;
use App\Models\Login;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AddLoan extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'amount' => 'required',
            'startDate' => 'required',
            'endDate' => 'required',
            'dateLoanSigned' => 'required',
            'interestRate' => 'required',
            'interestPaymentPeriod' => 'required',
            'interest_only_period' => 'required',
            'active' => 'required',
            'loanType' => 'required',
            'fName' => 'required',
            'lName' => 'required',
            'earnings' => 'required',
            'irdNum' => 'required',
            'bankAccNum' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $company_id = $request->user();
        dd($company_id);

        $loan = Loans::create([
            'companies_id' => $company_id,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'startDate' => $request->startDate,
            'endDate' => $request->endDate,
            'dateCreated' => $request->dateLoanSigned,
            'interestRate' => $request->interestRate,
            'interestPaymentPeriod' => $request->interestPaymentPeriod,
            'interestOnlyPeriod' => $request->interestOnlyPeriod,
            'active' => $request->active,
            'refinanced' => 0,
            'loanType' => $request->loanType
        ]);

        $loan->save();


        $lender = Lender::create([
            'fName' => $request->fName,
            'lName' => $request->lName,
            'annualEarnings' => $request->earnings,
            'irdNum' => $request->irdNum,
            'bankAccNum' => $request-> bankAccNum,
            'address' => $request-> address,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'loginID' => null
        ]);

        $lender->save();

        $taxAmount = DB::table('tax_rates')
                        ->where('minAmount', '<', $request->earnings)
                        ->where('maxAmount', '>', $request->earnings);

        $loanLender = LoanLenders::create([
            'loansID' => $loan->id,
            'lenderID' => $lender->id,
            'companyID' => $company_id,
            'taxAmount' => $taxAmount->id
        ]);

        $loanLender->save();

        $earningsReport = EarningsRecord::create([
            'lenderID' => $lender->id,
            'annualEarnings' => $lender->annualEarnings,
            'dateRecorded' => date('d-m-Y')
        ]);

        $earningsReport->save();

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

The route is called as a action in a form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('addLoan') }}">
```

The reason all of my validation is just looking for 'required' is because I wanted to make sure it wasn't validation failing and just not producing a error.

**What happens when I submit the form?**

When I submit the form and the route has the middleware attached to it, it simply redirects me back to the home screen.

**Cache**

I have already run:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `composer dump-autoload`

**Authentication Token**

As explained in the laravel documentation, I have already added the api_token column to the migration file for the User (in my case, I use the Login model for authentication). Below is the line in the migration file where I add that column:

```
$table->string('api_token', 80)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
```

This is the line in the documentation:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                        ->unique()
                        ->nullable()
                        ->default(null);
});
```

When I create the model object, I make the authenticated token by doing so:

```
'api_token' => Str::random(60)
```

When I check the database, I see that the api_token successfully has been added so I not sure to what the issue could be.

(The documentation link I used is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication))

Comment: You need to send the token as part of the request as it’s the token in the request that is used to determine if you’re authenticated.

Comment: Also, why are you using get on a store method, it should be post.

Comment: When I was testing, I tried everything to see if it would change anything and just forgot to change it back to post. Also thank you for the comments @Peppermintology, but I am unsure how to do that in my addLoan route.

Comment: I tried following the documentation but could not see anything about doing it in your route, instead they did it using request and assigned the returned value as a variable: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests

Comment: `<form method="GET" action="{{ url('') }}/api/addloancontroller">`   You may try this once

Comment: Same issue as before. No errors, but it does not even reach my store method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a route in your `api` routes file and protected it with the `auth:api` middleware (which is commonly `Passport`), yet you are calling the route from an HTML `form` which is not how you would typically consume an `api`.

I assume you're just looking to protect routes accessed via web pages within your application, therefore I suggest you research one of the `web` based authentication mechanisms for Laravel such as [`Fortify`](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) or if you don't want to roll your own views, either [`Jetstream`](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream) or [`Breeze`](https://github.com/laravel/breeze).

**Update**

Tokens are used in conjunction with an `api`, the workflow you've currently implemented (a web form) is a `web` workflow so using `api tokens` is not recommended.

The `Auth` facade is available in controller as long as a `user` is authenticated and works for both the `web` and `api` guards.

If you install either `Breeze` or `Jetstream`, which I would recommend over `Fortify` if you're just starting out, you will be able to use the `auth` middleware to protect your routes requiring `users` to authenticate themselves (login) in order to access a protected route. This then means that when a `user` has authenticated and you process a request in your controller `Auth::id()` will return the `id` of the authenticated `user`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The reason I am using the auth:api middleware was because I want to call Auth::id() in my controller to get the currently logged in users id yet it always returned null. So I did a lot of research and people were saying its due to authentication not being set up and that I had to use api_tokens. I just can not figure out how to send the api_tokens to the controller.

Comment: Thank you so much, changing it to a web route and using 'auth' instead of 'auth:api' solved it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommended make refactoring your code in the controller, is the first I create FormRequest for your method, and move your validation code and rules in there. In then in [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests) in method `authorize` I'm writing code like this:

```php
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return auth('auth:api')->check(); // Method check return false/true.
}

public function rules()
{
   return [
        'amount' => ['required'],
        'startDate' => ['required'],
        'endDate' => ['required'],
        'dateLoanSigned' => ['required'],
        'interestRate' => ['required'],
        'interestPaymentPeriod' => ['required'],
        'interest_only_period' => ['required'],
        'active' => ['required'],
        'loanType' => ['required'],
        'fName' => ['required'],
        'lName' => ['required'],
        'earnings' => ['required'],
        'irdNum' => ['required'],
        'bankAccNum' => ['required'],
        'address' => ['required'],
        'phone' => ['required']
   ];
}
```

also, I'm recommended to change the HTTP method `GET` to `POST`.